# Resurrecting old PLT-Scheme project (pre-1999)

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm trying to resurrect an old (1999 or earlier) project written in Scheme (PLT-Scheme, using the `mzscheme` interpreter (?) commandline tool). To make the matters worse, I don't know Scheme, or Lisp (in fact, I want to learn, but that's another story).

I have the source code of the project at:

> [github.com/akavel/sherman](https://github.com/akavel/sherman)

Now, when running the code, it bails out with an error message like below:

```
Sherman runtime version 0.5
Hosted on MzScheme version 52, Copyright (c) 1995-98 PLT (Matthew Flatt)
reference to undefined identifier: list->block
```

(I've tried PLT-Scheme versions [52, 53,](https://github.com/akavel/pltscheme-cvs-cvs2git-1) 103, 103p1. Earlier versions don't allow `mzscheme -L` option, which is referenced in the `sherman.bat` script used in the project. Later versions also have some more serious problems with the code or options.)

The difficulty is, that from what I see, `list->block` actually ***is*** defined - see: [`collects/sherman/BLOCK.SS` line 48](https://github.com/akavel/sherman/blob/master/collects/sherman/BLOCK.SS#L48). So, what is wrong?

To run the code, I perform the following steps:

1. Download PLT-Scheme v. 103p1 (from [the old versions download page](http://download.plt-scheme.org/mzscheme/all-versions.html) - first closing the *"PLT Scheme is now Racket"* banner) - for Windows, use: [mz-103p1-bin-i386-win32.zip](http://download.plt-scheme.org/bundles/103p1/mz/mz-103p1-bin-i386-win32.zip).
2. Unzip (e.g. to directory `c:\PLT`).
3. Copy `c:\sherman\collects\sherman` directory with contents to: `c:\PLT\collects\sherman` (where `c:\sherman` contains the contents of the [github repository](https://github.com/akavel/sherman)).
4. Run `cmd.exe`, then `cd c:\sherman`.
5. `set PATH=c:\PLT;%PATH%`
6. `sherman.bat run trivial.s`

   - this command is in fact, from what I understand, equivalent to:

```
(require-library "runtime.ss" "sherman")
(parameterize ((current-namespace sherman-namespace)) (load "trivial.s"))
(current-namespace sherman-namespace)
```

- After that, I get the error as described above (MzScheme version would be reported as 103p1 or whatever).

Could you help me solve the problem?

***EDIT 2: SOLVED!***

To whom it may concern, I've added a fully fledged ["How to use this project" instruction on the project page](https://github.com/akavel/sherman#how-to-use-this-project), detailing the solution to the problem thanks to [*soegaard*'s help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12551836/98528).

In short:

```
copy trivial.s trivial.rs
rem (the above is workaround for problems with 'r2s.exe < trivial.r > trivial.rs')
sherman.bat compile trivial.rs
sherman.bat run trivial.zo
rem (or: sherman.bat run trivial.ss)
```

Comment: Probably, it would be easier to port the relevant code to Racket, using `#lang mzscheme` at the top of each file.

Comment: @SamTobin-Hochstadt: Won't I have difficulties porting various calls to old libraries? From what I tried, e.g. the `(require-library)` form (used extensively in this project) is not even findable in the online Racket docs?

Comment: The `require-library` form is an ancient version of `require`. You probably want to read the [porting guides](http://docs.racket-lang.org/release/index.html) in the docs (which mentions `require-library`, for example).

Comment: @AsumuTakikawa: Ah, searched for something like this, but couldn't find. Thanks a lot for the link, may help!

Comment: From the last part of what you wrote, the biggest part of such porting would be to switch from `load` (which just evaluates all code in the toplevel environment) to modules.  Because of that, it will take more work than slapping a `#lang mzscheme` on files.  The question is how much work that will be...  (In some cases it's nearly trivial, in others it can be extremely hard.)

Comment: I had a quick look -- since it's JRM's project, your best bet is to ask him.  He might not be familiar enough with how Racket's module system is used these days, but he can probably tell you if switching to modules will be easy or not.

Comment: +1 purely because the question is so well-written. I have absolutely no idea what the answer is though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not an answer, but a few notes too big for a comment.

```
1. Sanity Check
```

The error message says `list->block` is undefined.
Make sure that the code in `block.ss` is run, by
inserting `(display "block.ss is loaded!")` in `block.ss`
just to make sure, the code is run.

---

```
2. Random Thoughts
```

The file `blocks.ss` begins with:

```
(require-library "functios.ss")
(require-library "synrule.ss")
(require-library "stream.ss" "sherman")
```

The file "sherman/stream.ss" is in the repository,
but where is "synrule.ss" and "functios.ss" ?

Ah... This code is old! Here is a description of
how `require-library` worked. It lists `functios.ss`
and `synrule.ss` as part of MzLib.

http://www.informatik.uni-kiel.de/~scheme/doc/mzscheme/node158.htm

Let's check out how `require-library` worked:

> When require-library is used to load a file, the library name and the
>   resulting value(s) are recored in a table associated with the current
>   namespace. If require-library is evaluated for a library that is
>   already registered in the current namespace's load table, then the
>   library is not loaded again; the result(s) recorded in the load table
>   is returned, instead.

So when the code in `block.ss` is run, the names are stored in a namespace. If the current namespace is the wrong one, when the code in `block.ss` is evaluated, it would explain you error message of `list->block` being undefined.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've already had a look definition of `sherman-namespace` in `runtime.ss`, but it didn't look suspicious enough (esp. that there was some kinda similar `#%list->block`), and now thanks to you this became more suspicious :) So, situation got better, but... still not exactly where I hoped to end... so I updated the question, and would be very grateful if you fancied enough to maybe hint me one bit more...

Comment: How exactly did you try to run the code in `trivial.s`? I believe `trivial.s` is the output of the lexer, so one must first compile it and then run it. The backquote thing is a way to avoid writing the lexer in Scheme (see Joe's comments in the readme).

Comment: AHH! Ok, your comment together with looking at various `extension`s + some experimentation finally did it for me: `copy trivial.s trivial.rs && sherman.bat compile trivial.rs && sherman.bat run trivial.zo`. BIG THANKS! (And the last patch with `list->block` needs to be reverted first)

Comment: Added a fully fledged ["How to use this project" instruction on the project page](https://github.com/akavel/sherman#how-to-use-this-project), based on all of that together.